# Database Web Frontend

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, web-applications

I'm looking for a **web frontend for end users** of our database (server runs either MySQL or Postgre) for organization-internal contacts and order handling.

I've searched the web for free/opensource database web frontends but only found admin tools (phpMyAdmin, ...) and frameworks that only show the tables but you cannot create apps (dadabik, vfront, xataface).

I want to **create apps like in Access forms** but apparently there is no such tool out there... As a backup, I would use openoffice Base with JDBC connection or progam the frontend in PHP manually.

An advantage would be **user authentication** (preferably LDAP).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will the end users customize/develop using the web frontend, or simply operate an app created by someone else?

Comment: They'll only operate the app, but the app should be developed quickly and easily using some kind of framework.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your project, I would suggest a [Model-View-Controller Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller). These typically have an [object-relational-mapper (ORM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) that makes it easy to design a front end for a database.

Some examples are:

- [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)
- [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)
- [ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Another CRUD builder is Crudin

With Crudin you can use to save hours and hours of programming when you have to build a custom CMS system, extranet or when you have to manage the content contained in a MySQL database

The Crudin not generates php files, it directly generates the interface. With a change in the database the system automatically fits, without any line of programmming.

http://crudin.smarc.com.br/en

Comment: I just tried this and I found the user interface was a mixture of English and non-English!